# invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, matrix

I want to implement the solver for a tridiagonal matrix-vector, that is Ax=b. While writing the loop section, it shows that 'invalid index to scalar variable.'I want to know why and how to fix it. Here's my code.

```
import numpy as np

def tmv_solver(a,b,c,d):
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    c = np.array(c)
    d = np.array(d)
    n = len(a)
    x = []
    b_star = []
    d_star = []
    b_star = b[0]
    d_star = d[0]
    for i in range(1,n):
        b_star = np.append(b_star,b[i]-a[i+1]/b_star[i]*c[i])
        d_star = np.append(d_star,d[i+1]-a[i+1]/b_star[i]*d_star[i])
        if b_star[i] == 0:
            return 'Error'
    x[-1] = d_star[-1]/b_star[-1]
    for i in range(n-1,-1):
        x.append((d_star[i]-b_star[i+1]*x[i])/b_star[i])
    return x

#small test
a = [1,1,1]
b = [-2,-2,-2,-2]
c = [1,1,1]
d = [0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4]
y = tmv_solver(a,b,c,d)
print y
```

The problem shows up at  `b_star = np.append(b_star,b[i]-a[i+1]/b_star[i]*c[i])` for 'invalid index to scalar variable.'

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Post your code in your question with proper formatting. Don't give us an image of it.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited it again.

Comment: `np.append(b_star,b[i]-a[i+1]/b_star[i]*c[i])`. `-a[i+1]` will attempt to access `a` at an invalid index since `n` is already defined as the `len()` of `a`. Normally the process would terminate without the invalid index with `for i in range(1,n):`, but you're adding 1 to the index when accessing `a`.

Comment: Also actually the error indicates that you have issues before that point. Since it specifically references a scalar, note that you have `b_star = b[0]` which is just `-2`. You cannot index that number with `b_star[i]`.

Comment: So my point is to initialize the value of b_star as b[0]. In that case, should I write as `b_star.append(b[0])`?

Comment: That still looks like it would fail. I can't see anywhere where `b_star` gets appended to, so your solution would simply create a single-item list and indexing by `i` will still throw `IndexError`. If `b_star` is only ever meant to take a single value at any one time, remove the `i` index on it. Whether that computationally does what you want to achieve, I don't know.

Comment: Wait, is the purpose to have `b` always one index ahead of `b_star` and `b_star` should also increment through the array on each iteration? `b[0]` does not _set the current element of a list to start at_, it simply pulls out the (in this case) integer that is at that index in the list. At that point, you no-longer have a list.